# Encoding is not kept

Tags: python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 and using google plus public API to get activity data in a file. I am encountering issues to maintain the json encoding in my file. Double quotes are coming as u'' in my file. Below is my code:

```
from apiclient import discovery

API_KEY = 'MY API KEY'
service = discovery.build("plus", "v1", developerKey=API_KEY)

activities_resource = service.activities()
request = activities_resource.search(query='India versus South  Africa', maxResults=1, orderBy='best',)
while request!= None:
      activities_document = request.execute()
      if 'items' in activities_document:
         with open("output.json", mode='a') as file:
             data = str(activities_document['items'])
             file.write(data +"\n\n")

   request = service.activities().list_next(request, activities_document)
```

Output:
[{u'kind': u'plus#activity', u'provider': {u'title': u'Google+'}, u'titl.......

I am expecting [{"kind": "plus#activity", .....

I am running my code on windows and I have tried both on DOS and pycharm IDE. I have also run the code on ubuntu machine but same output. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you believe the output to be incorrect?

Comment: I am loading this output to mongoDB and it gives me an error:

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:

If I manually edit the file and replace u' ' with " " ; it moves to the next column and throws error on next unicode  u' ' instance.

Answer (score 0):

The [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module is used for generating JSON. Use it.